# Adding a Microsoft List inside a sharepoint site will not have any site content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, sharepoint-list

Inside our modern team site i added some Microsoft lists as follow:-

[image]

but i have noted something is that inside these lists >> their content types only contain list columns and there are not any site columns or site content types for these Microsoft lists .. so is this a limitation/issue ? as we were always been advised to create site columns and site content types to facilitate re-usability inside our sharepoint sites.. but seems Microsoft lists themselves do not follow these guidelines and best practices!!as seems there are not site columns and site content types created for these lists!!

here is a list content type for a MS lists:-

[image]

and here is its site content type with only Title column:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is simply how Microsoft Lists works. If you believe it should be harnessing Site Content Types when creating new lists, then you can raise this on the user voice for SharePoint or Microsoft 365:

[SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/)

[Office 365 UserVoice](https://office365.uservoice.com/)

Comment: ok will raise a user voice..

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft list  only with a title column by default, in order to allow users to customize the list to the maximum extent.

Comment: i did not get your point... now if you chose one of the templates you will get additional fields beside the Title